# MAX31865 and MAX31855 Completely not Working

Tags: spi, esp32, rtd, max31865

I am beginner in Electronics.

While working with MAX31865 and MAX31855 Modules it was working perfectly, but after designing custom PCB based on modules its not working.

RTD shows -242C and 982C randomly and Thermocouple shows -100C, is there any problem with schematic ?

Tried Removing series Voltage level shifter but same result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you’re using diodes and pull-ups for SPI?  CS and MOSI are outputs from the micro and MISO should tri-state from any device that has CS inactive.  The diodes may not allow the signals to pull low enough, try linking across them and maybe remove the pull-ups, which should be unnecessary.

Comment: SDI and SDO corresponding to MOSI and MISO in your schematic

Comment: @Frog I tried removing all diodes in SPI lines and sort them, and open Pull up resistor but ended with same result also SDI and SDO is taken as MOSI & MISO respectively

Comment: Do you have access to an oscilloscope to check the signals?

Comment: I am purchasing logic analyzer for this but still before that if anyone can find problem in schematic

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. As @Frog said in the comments, you would need a oscilloscope to spot the exact issue.

The datasheet does not mention it, but you need a pull-down resistor on MISO (SDO) line. These MAX ICs's SDO line does not pull itself down. It only pulls the line UP, for some reason.

You would need a oscilloscope to detect this issue, not a logic analyzer. You would see the MISO line go like this:

[image: SDO.png]

I used a resistor of 560 Ohms to pull the SDO line down and worked like charm.

A second thing to take into account, is the Capacitance of the Diodes you are using. if its too much, it will delay the signal rise up times. A workaround to that (if you don't have other diode types available) is to lower the frequency of the SPI protocol so the voltage will have more time to rise.

Comment: Will try that !

Comment: @JayVadoliya just out of interest: do the modules you used and which worked have this pulldown?

Comment: No They have Voltage level shifter in SPI lines here is the link https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/37310